# How to show that $n$th prime is less than $2^n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I know that there are better lower bounds for number of primes less than n but I don't know how to solve this problem using fundamental proof. I tried using sieve of Eratosthenes and using induction on n to solve the problem but those techniques didn't work. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: It's fairly easy to prove that $\pi(n)>\frac {\log_2(n)}2$  (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502852/pix-geqslant-frac-log-x2-log2-for-all-x-geqslant2))...but you want $\pi(n)>{\log_2(n)}$.  Not sure there is an elementary way to do that.

Comment: There isn't a known simple answer (one that doesn't use Betrand's postulate) according to the answers I got here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500149/simpler-proof-that-pi2n-geq-n

Comment: Possibly you mean $p_n<2^{2n-1}$, which has a very elementary solution, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651253/prove-that-the-nth-prime-number-p-n-satisfies-p-n-leq-22n-1?rq=1)?

Answer (score 2):

The inductive step needs [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate). Every number theorist should read its proof once.

Alternatively, if one gets an upper bound on the relative error in $p_n\sim n\ln n$ (a consequence of the prime number theorem), one can use $n\ln n\in o(2^n)$ to prove the result once a suitable base case is checked.

Comment: Yes it does. Isn't there a simpler approach?

Comment: @EhsanPoursaeed I doubt it. When a sequence's common ratios are $<2$, I doubt a proof of the upper bound $2^n$ can avoid using that fact.

Comment: @J.G. The statement that $p_n\lt 2^n$ is much weaker than the statement that $p_{n+1}\lt 2p_n$; I wouldn't be surprised if there's an easier proof. (Modulo the comments above, which suggest otherwise. :/ )